# Error: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, build.gradle

I am trying to run my program using  `flutter run`, but it seems like it's giving me an error.

It says that

`A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle`

I edited my build.gradle compileSdkVersion, but it's still causing me issues. I don't know what is wrong here. I even changed it from compileSdk to compileSdkVersion.

Here is my build.gradle\app:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.gmapsapi"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.gmapsapi"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdk 20 
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'  // Example dependency

}
```

Here is my build.gradle\android:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google() // Add Google repository for Google services plugin
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // Define dependencies for the build script
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1' // Corrected dependency notation
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
compileSdkVersion 34
```

with

```
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
```